# Get points x distance inside a polygon

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector

I can't figure out a way to do this. I have a list of vector2 points and I need all the points which are inside that polygon with a `x` distance.

So I have a `List` of *Green* points and looking for a `List` of *Red* points that have a `x` distance from respective green points.

[image]

I am thinking of getting 2 imaginary points, 1 unity towards the previous and next point.
Then moving towards the center of that 2 points by `x` distance. But then if the inter angle is not 90 then it will move outside of the polygon.

```
Vector2 me = point; // point
Vector2 next = n_point; // on left
Vector2 previous = p_point; // on right
//Debug.DrawLine(me, (me - next), Color.green);
// 2 points ep1 & ep2 
Vector2 center = Vector2.Lerp(ep1,ep2, 0.5f); 
Vector2 finalpoint = Vector2.Lerp(me,center,0.1f); //move towards center
```

[image]

I think I am overthinking this. Is there a super-easy way to do this?

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_curve . It being a polygon makes it easier, but not 'super easy'

Comment: Draw a circle with center being red point and radius being the distance.  Then find green points inside the circle.  Ninety degrees isn't important.  d= sqrt(x**2 + y**2).

Comment: Are the points ordered clock-wise or counter-clock-wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all the edges are either horizontal or vertical I would simply consider each possible case separately.

Get the direction vectors.

```
Vector2 from = me - previous;
Vector2 to = next - me;
```

I also assume that there is always a turn. I.e., if `from` is horizontal, then `to` is vertical and vice versa. Either `x` or `y` is `0.0f` and the other coordinate is not zero.
I also assume that the x-axis points to the right and the y-axis upwards.
Assuming points are listed clock-wise.

```
float x, y;
if (from.x > 0.0f) { // from points to the right
    y = me.y - distance;
    if (to.y > 0.0f) x = me.x + distance else x = me.x - distance;
} else if (from.x < 0.0f) { // from points to the left
    y = me.y + distance;
    if (to.y > 0.0f) x = me.x + distance else x = me.x - distance;
} else if (from.y > 0.0f) { // from points upwards
    x = me.x + distance;
    if (to.x > 0.0f) y = me.y - distance else y = me.y + distance;
} else { // from.y < 0.0f, points downwards
    x = me.x - distance;
    if (to.x > 0.0f) y = me.y - distance else y = me.y + distance;
}
Vector2 me_inner = new Vector2(x, y);
```

I hope I got all the signs right.

Comment: This worked as all the assumptions are right.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods that spring to mind

Option1:

1. For each line define a normal, i.e. a perpendicular line pointing outward
2. Define a normal for each vertex as the average of the normals of the lines the vertex is part of.
3. Move the vertex X units along the normal.

This is fairly easy to implement, but may have problems with self-intersection for some kinds of geometry.

Option2:

1. For each line define a normal, i.e. a perpendicular line pointing outward
2. Move each line-segment X Units along the normal.
3. for each sequential pair of line segments determine if:
4. the two line segments intersect, if so, use the intersection point as the vertex. i.e. add the intersection point into your point-list.
5. If they do not intersect, insert a new line segment between the start and end point of the lines. i.e. Insert both start and end vertex to your point-list.

This should handle self-intersection better, but there might still be problem-cases. And it a bit more cumbersome to implement. It somewhat depend on how exact you need the new line positioned, and well it should handle different kinds of geometry.